# Sass nested lists index error on each loop when using nth?

Tags: css, sass

So I'm trying to get the following result in CSS using the below Sass code:

```
.term-formal-wear .products .title, .term-fw-fall-winter .products .title, .term-fw-spring-summer .products .title {
    background-color: #d4af37;
}
.term-formal-wear .products .title h2, .term-fw-fall-winter .products .title h2, .term-fw-spring-summer .products .title h2 {
    color: #000;
}
```

And so on and so forth for each of the categories (this is for WordPress).

Here's the Sass:

```
$cat-prop-vals: (
    (formal-wear, fw, $cieanna-gold, #000),
    (night-wear, nw, $cieanna-rose-gold, #000),
    (ready-to-wear, rtw, $cieanna-dark-gray, #fff),
    (sports-wear, sw, #000, #fff)
);

@each $cat-prop-val in $cat-prop-vals {
    .term-#{nth(#{$cat-prop-val}, 1)}, .term-#{nth(#{$cat-prop-val}, 2)}-fall-winter, .term-#{nth(#{$cat-prop-val}, 2)}-spring-summer {
        & .products .title {
            background-color: #{nth(#{$cat-prop-val}, 3)};
            h2 {
                color: #{nth(#{$cat-prop-val}, 4)};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting `Error: List index is 2 but list is only 1 item long for nth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing a list to `nth()`, you're passing a string.  Instead of passing the `$cat-prop-val` list to `nth()`, you're passing the literal string `"$cat-prop-val"`.  When you use the string interpolation syntax (`#{}`), all you're ever going to get is a string.  So, don't do that unless you want a string.

```
@each $cat-prop-val in $cat-prop-vals {
    .term-#{nth($cat-prop-val, 1)}, .term-#{nth($cat-prop-val, 2)}-fall-winter, .term-#{nth($cat-prop-val, 2)}-spring-summer {
        // stuff
    }
}
```